# Can I figuratively use "jump" when talking about conclusions?

Tags: phrase-request

In Italian, *saltare* ("jump") is a verb that is figuratively used in many cases, such as in *saltare a certe conclusioni*, which is used when somebody, basing on some known facts, deduces something that somebody else doesn't see as an obvious conclusion.

For example, if somebody is the last person seen with somebody else who died, and they have been seen fighting between each other, that person could be investigated for murdering. His lawyer would say that thinking he is the murder would be *saltare a certe conclusioni*, since his customer has been seen with the person who died 24 hours before he died, and it is still not clear if that person was killed, or died because an accident.

What is the equivalent of *saltare a certe conclusioni* I should use in English?

Comment: See this fun episode of "around the world in 80 days": http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U3JTZabBKDo&list=PL8WaZgQZVBkcfCNVlUan4reSEalgXEu3F

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jump to a conclusion is perfectly acceptable and known.  Similarly, leap to a conclusion is also acceptable.  These can be used as forms such as: leaping to conclusions, jumped to the wrong conclusion, etc.

You could even extend this to create something like *vaulting to a conclusion* - which I would take to mean that the 'jump' has been made with very little evidence to support the conclusion arrived at.

Comment: While one **could** extend this to _vault_, I think it's worth pointing out that such usage might sound awkward, or at least unfamiliar. _Jump to conclusions_ is almost idiomatic, _leap_ is used on occasion, and _vault_ flatlines on an [Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=jump+to+conclusions%2Cleap+to+conclusions%2Cvault+to+conclusions&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=). I'd interpret all three to mean "conclude hastily without supporting evidence," but assume that the rarer words were meant to imply particularly hasty conclusions.

Comment: Once it's in place it invites extension: hopping to a conclusion, stumbling to a conclusion, shambling to a conclusion, sidling to a conclusion, frog-marching the reader to a conclusion ...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can jump to a conclusion in English. (A lawyer, by the way, has clients rather than customers.)